# Why is Windows Authentication failing to authenticate without the authorization fallback policy set to default?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, windows-authentication

I've been digging for a while and probably am missing a fine detail in the documentation.  I am using Negotiate to authenticate users in a blazor server appication.  My setup is as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Authenticated", p =>
        p.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    );
});
```

I have added Authentication and Authorization to the pipeline:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

In my primary App component, I am attempting to determine if the user is authenticated.  For development, I have another Authentication service that isn't in play here.  When a user isn't present under that situation, I would like the `ExternalLayout` to show.  By default, authentication always returns `NoResult`, and therefore the page says "This user doesn't exist".  When I add `options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy` to my authorization setup, authentication is successful and the user identity is populated.  I do not wish to set the FallbackPolicy because I get a blank screen when the user is not authenticated.  Below is my `App.razor` code.

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView Policy="Authenticated">
        <Authorized>
            <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
                <Found Context="routeData">
                    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                        <NotAuthorized Context="routeViewContext">
                            <AdminContacts>
                                <em>You cannot access the resource.</em>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <em>Contact an administrator to change permissions:</em>
                            </AdminContacts>
                        </NotAuthorized>
                    </AuthorizeRouteView>
                </Found>
                <NotFound>
                    <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col p-3">
                                    <em>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </LayoutView>
                </NotFound>
            </Router>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(ExternalLayout)">
                <AdminContacts>
                    <em>This user doesn't exist.</em>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <em>Contact an administrator for help:</em>
                </AdminContacts>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

As you can see, I have tried manually adding an Authenticated policy, but I believe this is the default anyway.

Thanks!  Any help you can offer is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The built-in [AuthenticationStateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-server-authentication) service for Blazor Server apps obtains authentication state data from ASP.NET Core's HttpContext.User. This is how authentication state integrates with existing ASP.NET Core authentication mechanisms.

[Please refer the sample code from official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authenticationstateprovider-service).

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

...

    
var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
var user = authState.User;

if (user.Identity is not null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)IsAuthenticated)
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't helpful for solving my problem.  Authentication is failing to complete.  The user is not populated.

Comment: Hi @Macadameane, could you share the minimal sample project for me and hide your sensitive information, I am willing to investigate the issue tomorrow.

Comment: I'll try to put something together, but I'm currently busy